# Error while running migrate for django-hordak

Tags: python, django, pip

I want to use django-hordak in my application for accounting purpose and have followed the official tutorial at http://django-hordak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. 
I add the applications "mptt" and "hordak" in INSTALLED_APPS and when I run ./manage.py migrate, it throws following error on the console: 
[image]

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Try `pip install sqlparse`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. It required postgres as database backend to run. Added following to settings.py and then it worked fine.

`'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'accounting',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }`

Answer (score 1):

As told in the error message

> No module named 'sqlparse'

The below exception tells you:

> sqlparse is required if your don't split your SQL statements manually

Run `pip install sqlparse`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but now it gives this error: `Applying hordak.0002_check_leg_trigger_20160903_1149...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fatah/virtualenvs/django1.10/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/fatah/virtualenvs/django1.10/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 335, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "OR": syntax error`

Comment: Read [the requirements](http://django-hordak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements) - you use sqlite3 and the app requires postgresql. Looks like it executes queries that sqlite3 does not understand.